# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'optionOne')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried many thing to solve this problem but I am not able to find the solution. My reducer function always giving same error. I don't what's wrong with my code . If some can help me in debugging It will be a great help. when I try to log (state) it gives proxy array but on other hand when I log current state it return data. I am adding the reducer code below and [github link](https://github.com/vwadhwa3/ReactProject2EmpPoll.git)

```
import { createSlice ,current} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"; 
import {_saveQuestion,_saveQuestionAnswer} from '../_DATA';
 

const allQuestionSlice = createSlice({

    name:"allQuestion",
    initialState:{
        allQuestion:null
    },
    reducers:{
       allQuestionData :(state,action)=>{
            state.allQuestion = action.payload
         },  
         addNewAnswer(state  , action) {       

          if (action.payload.option === "optionOne") {
            state.allQuestion[action.payload.qid]["optionOne"].votes.push(action.payload.authedUser);
            } else if (action.payload.option === "optionTwo") {
            state.allQuestion[action.payload.qid]["optionTwo"].votes.push(action.payload.authedUser);
            }
             
 
          // const {allQuestion} = current(state)         
          // if (action.payload.option === "optionOne") {
          //   allQuestion.filter( x=> x.id == action.payload.id)[0].optionOne.votes.concat(action.payload.userid)    
          //   console.log(    allQuestion.filter( x=> x.id == action.payload.id)[0].optionOne.votes.concat(action.payload.userid)    )        
          // } else if (action.payload.option === "optionTwo") {
          //   allQuestion.filter( x=> x.id == action.payload.id)[0].optionTwo.votes.concat(action.payload.userid)
          //   console.log(  allQuestion.filter( x=> x.id == action.payload.id)[0].optionTwo.votes.concat(action.payload.userid) )
          // }
        },
  },

    extraReducers: (b) => {
        b.addCase("addQuestion", (state, action) => {             
            state.allQuestion.push( action.payload);        
          });
          
        
      },    
    })




export const saveQuestion=(saveQuestionData)=>async(d)=>{
    const data = await _saveQuestion(saveQuestionData);
    d({type:"addQuestion",payload:data});
};
  
// export const addNewAnswer =({ authedUser, qid, answer})=>async(d)=>{
//   debugger
//   const data = await _saveQuestionAnswer({ authedUser, qid, answer});
//   d({type:"addAnswer",payload:data});
// };
export const {allQuestionData ,addNewAnswer} = allQuestionSlice.actions;

export default allQuestionSlice.reducer;
```

Different code that I tried to implement but did not succeed.

```
import { createSlice ,current} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"; 
import {_saveQuestion,_saveQuestionAnswer} from '../_DATA';
 

const allQuestionSlice = createSlice({

    name:"allQuestion",
    initialState:{
        allQuestion:null
    },
    reducers:{
       allQuestionData :(state,action)=>{
            state.allQuestion = action.payload
         },  
         addNewAnswer(state , action) {   
          const { authedUser , qid ,option  } = action.payload
          // { authedUser: loggedInUser, qid: question_id, option: event };
          return {
            ...state.value,
            [qid]: {
              ...state.value[qid],
              optionOne: {
                votes:
                option === "optionOne"
                    ? state.value[qid].optionOne.votes.concat([authedUser])
                    : state.value[qid].optionOne.votes,
              },
              optionTwo: {
                votes:
                option === "optionTwo"
                    ? state.value[qid].optionTwo.votes.concat([authedUser])
                    : state.value[qid].optionTwo.votes,
              },
            },
          }



          // return {
          //   ...state,
          //   [qid]: {
          //     ...state[qid],
          //     optionOne: {
          //       votes:
          //         option === "optionOne"
          //           ? state[qid].optionOne.votes.concat([authedUser])
          //           : state[qid].optionOne.votes,
          //     },
          //     optionTwo: {
          //       votes:
          //         option === "optionTwo"
          //           ? state[qid].optionTwo.votes.concat([authedUser])
          //           : state[qid].optionTwo.votes,
          //     },
          //   },
 
          // };
        },
  },

    extraReducers: (b) => {
        b
        .addCase("addQuestion", (state, action) => {             
            state.allQuestion.push( action.payload);        
          })
        .addCase("ANSWER_QUESTION", (state, action) => {
            // const questions = {
            //   ...state.value,
            //   [action.payload.qid]: {
            //     ...state.value[action.payload.qid],
            //     [action.payload.answer]: {
            //       ...state.value[action.payload.qid][action.payload.answer],
            //       votes: state.value[action.payload.qid][
            //         action.payload.answer
            //       ].votes.concat([action.payload.authedUser]),
            //     },
            //   },
            // };
           // state.value = questions;

           console.log(current(state))


          })

         

      },  
        
    })




export const saveQuestion=(saveQuestionData)=>async(d)=>{
    const data = await _saveQuestion(saveQuestionData);
    d({type:"addQuestion",payload:data});
};
  
// export const saveQuestionAnswer = ({ authedUser, qid, answer }) =>
//   async (dispatch) => {
//     const data = await _saveQuestionAnswer({ authedUser, qid, answer });

//     dispatch({ type: "ANSWER_QUESTION", payload: { authedUser, qid, answer } });
//   };
export const {allQuestionData ,addNewAnswer} = allQuestionSlice.actions;

export default allQuestionSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: either `state.allQuestion[action.payload.qid]` or `state.value[qid]` is `undefined` depending on which line of your code throws the error - that's the first step in troubleshooting your problem - determining which line of code is throwing the error (it'll be in the error message)

Comment: @JaromandaX  both of them are giving me same error. I am not able figure out what wrong with my code

Comment: @JaromandaX  when try to console.log(state) it prints proxy but when console.log(curent(state)) it prints the actual array

Comment: so, `state` is an **array** ... array's don't generally have a `.value` property - but if `state` is a `proxy` what is it a `proxy` for, what is `state.value` ... what is `state.value[qid]` ... really, you say both `state.allQuestion[action.payload.qid]` and `state.value[qid]` are undefined, so, that's the issue you need to troubleshoot ... why are they `undefined` - perhaps it's the value of `action.payload.qid` or `qid` that cause the issue - what value do they have? is it a value you expected?

Comment: when I log state @JaromandaX
console.log(state)  
Output

Proxy
[[Handler]]: null
[[Target]]: null
[[IsRevoked]]: true

Comment: when I log console.log(current(state)) @JaromandaX

output 

Object
allQuestion: Array(6)
0: {id: '8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd', author: 'sarahedo', timestamp: 1467166872634, optionOne: {…}, optionTwo: {…}}
1: {id: '6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez', author: 'mtsamis', timestamp: 1468479767190, optionOne: {…}, optionTwo: {…}}
 
5: {id: 'xj352vofupe1dqz9emx13r', author: 'mtsamis', timestamp: 1493579767190, optionOne: {…}, optionTwo: {…}}length: 
6[[Prototype]]: Array(0)[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: ahhh ... can't read stuff that should be in the question

Comment: can you please help @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your exact question, but if you are trying to solve the problem of getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'optionOne')` you must do this:
first allQuestions is null

```
    initialState:{
        allQuestion:null
    },
```

if you want to add data to an object, it must exist as an object, not null nor undefined, so you must change it to

```
    initialState:{
        allQuestion:{}
    },
```

now you can add something to this object using [] notation, but it does not work if you want to chain it, because allQuestion["something"] is undefined, and you cannot use [] notation to add to an undefined, so you must go one by one, or first create another object like  `const a = {optionOne: {votes:["somedata"]}}` and then add it to allQuestion.

```
if (action.payload.option === "optionOne") {
   if(state.allQuestion?.[action.payload.qid]?.["optionOne"]?.votes)
      state.allQuestion[action.payload.qid]["optionOne"].votes.push(action.payload.authedUser);
   else
      state.allQuestion[action.payload.qid] = {optionOne:{votes:[action.payload.authedUser]}}
    
} else if (action.payload.option === "optionTwo") {
   if(state.allQuestion?.[action.payload.qid]?.["optionTwo"]?.votes)
   state.allQuestion[action.payload.qid]["optionTwo"].votes.push(action.payload.authedUser);
else
   state.allQuestion[action.payload.qid] = {optionTwo:{votes:[action.payload.authedUser]}}
}
```

you can optimize your code a lot, but I'm not going to do that for you.

Comment: thank you for the help but it is still giving error. Error: [Immer] Immer only supports setting array indices and the 'length' property